# what object gets extracted by lambda function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Consider the following example,
- given a DataFrame has a column x
- calculating x^2, x^3,... and append to the original DataFrame

```
# platform info.
import sys
print sys.version

# this example is to show how to calculate features of x, x^2, x^3...
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([2], columns=['x'])
print df

for i in range(4):
    # trying to extract first and last column, then multiply them and append to the right
    # method 1 works
    df2 = df.iloc[:,[0,-1]].apply(lambda (x,y):x*y, axis=1)
    print df2.shape
    df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
print df.head(1)

df = pd.DataFrame([2], columns=['x'])
for i in range(4):
    # trying to extract first and last column, then multiply them and append to the right
    # method 2 doesn't work as expected. Why?
    df2 = df.apply(lambda x:x[0]*x[-1], axis=1)
    print df2.shape
    df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
print df.head(1)
```

Can you tell me the difference between the two methods? For the second example, what object I am extracting by using lambda function against df? I was expecting a row vector but it isn't.

Thanks!

Below is my running result:

```
2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)]
   x
0  2
(1,)
(1,)
(1,)
(1,)
   x  0  0   0   0
0  2  4  8  16  32
(1,)
(1,)
(1, 2)
(1, 4)
   x  0   0   0    0     0     0      0      0
0  2  4  16  64  256  1024  4096  16384  65536
```

Comment: Have you tried taking it out of a lambda into a function and then print it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. what part are you referring to  Can you elaborate ?  A little bit history here... I first tried method 2, it doesn't work. Then tried method 1, it worked. I want to know why method 2 doesn't work as expected.

Comment: What does *doesn't work as expected* mean? How doesn't it etc...?

Comment: I add my running result. Hopefully you can see what I mean by the different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your 'unexpected' behavior is coming from the difference in x[0] and x[-1] of your lambda function. While x[-1] returns a slice of the Series (the last value), x[0] will return the all rows where the index is 0 (which means all rows in your case since they get there index from the dataframe).
You can fix this behavior by using iloc for the lookup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([2], columns=['x'])
for i in range(4):
    df2 = df.apply(lambda x:x.iloc[0]*x.iloc[-1], axis=1)
    print df2.shape
    df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
print df.head(1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! lambda function still return a row vector, but x[0] is not the first element, it returns all columns ( not rows I think ) whose column names evaluates to 0. Since I didn't specify the columns names for df2, all the appended column names are 0. Therefore, x[0] will return [4], [4,16], [4,16,64,256], ...   and you fix worked.